# Missing Step in a Paper of Struwe.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

In [this paper](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~struwe/CV/papers/Critical-Wave-2D.pdf) on Page 4, in the last line of the proof, the author asserts that if a radial function $u:\mathbb{R_t}\times \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, smooth outside the origin $(0_t,0_x)$, admits for some $T,R>0$ a uniform bound on $||\nabla^2 u||_{L^2B(t+R/2)}$ for $0<t<T$ then the radial function can be smoothly extended to a neighborhood of $(0_t,0_x)$.

The author claims this follows from standard results, but I'm having a hard time figuring out which standard results he's referring to.

Comment: The standard results he is referring to is the local well posedness for $\Box u = f(u)$, which on dimension $\mathbb{R}_t\times\mathbb{R}^m$ holds for $H^k$ initial data as long as $k > m/2$. (See Theorem 5.1 and Remark 5.3 of Shatah and Struwe, _Geometric Wave Equations_.) A easily corollary is the following: for the equation $\Box u = f(u)$, consider initial data in $C^\infty_0$. Suppose that the solution exists in $[0,T)$ and such that $\sup_{(t,x)\in [0,T)\times\mathbb{R}^m} |u| < \infty$, then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that the solution extends smoothly to $[0,T+\epsilon)$.

Comment: This is known as a breakdown criterion. Some version of it should be contained in either Sogge's _Nonlinear Wave Equations_ or Hormander's _Nonlinear Hyperbolic Equations_ (unfortunately I don't have my copies handy to check). The usual versions though are proven for quasilinear wave equations and hence require sup bounds on $|u|, |\partial u|$, and $|\partial^2 u|$. But in the semilinear case with power nonlinearities the proof simplifies and a bound on $|u|$ is sufficient.